# Spring 3 Internationalization by folder

Tags: spring, properties, internationalization

I want to use Spring's i18n utility in a manner that all languages are separated by folders. I plan to use this kind of folder structure to keep things more organized than having all in one folder:

- i18n

  - en

    - messages.properties
    - application.properties
  - fr

    - messages.properties
    - application.properties

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes it is.

A simple solution I initially thought of was to setup a message source with the [`basenames`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasenames%28java.lang.String...%29) property, something like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>i18n.en.messages</value>
            <value>i18n.en.application</value>
            <value>i18n.fr.messages</value>
            <value>i18n.fr.application</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Giving it a second thought though, I realized **the above won't work**. Based on the [`ResourceBundle`s strategy to instantiate bundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29), given a name for a bundle, the first name in the bundle list would resolve the bundle (e.g. looking for `messages_fr.properties` the strategy will look for `i18n/en/messages_fr.properties` and then get resolved to `i18n/en/messages.properties` as the default when `messages_fr.properties` is not found).

You will need something that discovers your bundles based on a custom folder configuration.  **You will have to write your own [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) implementation** and use it in your application instead of the default ones provided by Spring. A basic implementation could look like this:

```
package pack.age;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class ByFolderResourceBundleMessageSource extends ResourceBundleMessageSource {
    private String rootFolder;

    @Override
    protected ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(String basename, Locale locale) {
        String langCode = locale.getLanguage().toLowerCase();
        String fullBaseName = this.rootFolder + "." + langCode + "." + basename;

        ResourceBundle bundle = super.getResourceBundle(fullBaseName, locale);
        if (bundle == null) {
            String defaultBaseName = this.rootFolder + ".Default." + basename;
            bundle = super.getResourceBundle(defaultBaseName, locale);
        }
        return bundle;
    }

    public void setRootFolder(String rootFolder) {
        this.rootFolder = rootFolder;
    }
}
```

Configuration like:

```
<bean id="messageSource" 
        class="pack.age.ByFolderResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="rootFolder" value="i18n" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
            <value>application</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And with a folder setup like:

```
i18n
  ├───Default
  │     ├─── application.properties
  │     └─── messages.properties
  │
  ├─── en
  │     ├─── application.properties
  │     └─── messages.properties
  │
  └─── fr
        ├─── application.properties
        └─── messages.properties
```